# AngularJS ui-select2 placeholder not showing inside nested ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, jquery-select2

whew, ok. scoping nightmares.

My placeholders in my inputs are not showing, they work as standalone inputs - but as soon as they are added to a list they lose scope. I have identified the issue - but I can't find a workaround - I think if I can understand this issue it will help solve a lot of my scoping questions in Angular. How do I manage scope in this scenario? even a resource would help

HTML

```
<div ng-repeat="region in data.regions">
    <h2> {{region.name}} </h2>
    <input ui-select2="version2" type="hidden" name="keywordsLocal-{{$index}}" class="region-keywords input-xlarge" data-ng-model="data.regions[$index].keywords" required-multiple />
    <select ui-select2 id="copy-{{$index}}" ng-show="region.length > 1" class="input-xlarge" ng-click="_copy($event, $index)" data-ng-model="data.regions[$index].keywords">
        <option value="">Placeholder:</option>
        <option ng-repeat="region in data.regions" value="{{region.keywords}}">{{region.name}}</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

IMAGE

[image]

Comment: Cau you provide us a fiddle of the problem. i'm not seeing any placeholder attribute in the input textbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this. In the documentation - it clearly states that select2 is 'incompatible' with the ng-options directive. This caused me a whole day of confusion because my entire app was buggy using ng-repeat.

I switched back over to ng-options and everything is working splendidly.

edit: added code example

```
<select class='copy' ng-change='_copyKeyword($index)' ng-disabled='max.keywords - keywordsSum() <= data.selected_region_objects.length' ng-model='selectedKeywords' ng-options='region.name for region in data.selected_region_objects | keywordFilter: {name: region.name}' style='width:200px;' ui-select2=''>
    <option value=''>Use same keywords as:</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Could you elaborate? How did you get select2 functionality with ng-options?